# Combining All JS and Add to Page or Reference Externally

Tags: javascript

I have about ten javascript files which make up a single page application.  I'm not using a framework like AngularJS or Backbone.  Now, eight of these files are singular to just one page, they're not used anywhere else on the site.

My question:  Should I combine these files into one and then inject them into the HTML, or should I combine them and reference them as an external file w/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Part of the answer certainly depends upon your workflow -- are you currently using a system to automatically combine and minify them? Reducing the number of Requests a client's browser/device has to make is usually the best solution.

Personally I would probably combine, minify, and load everything as a single external (or possibly two depending on A) dependencies and B) what makes logical sense) or two external .js files.

Comment: So I combine and minify them when I release the code to production.  Nothing is done dynamically.